# On the Identity matrix minus discrete laplacian

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-differences, laplacian

I am trying to figure out a way to bound the following expression
$\| (I - \alpha^2 D)^{-1} \| $,
where:

# $\alpha>0$

# $I$ is the identity matrix $(n\times n)$

# $D$ is the matrix obtained by discretizing the Laplace operator on a uniform grid (with given mesh size $\Delta x$ ) with central second order finite difference scheme, with periodic B.C.'s

# the norm we use is the operator from $R^n$ to $R^n$, with $R^n$ endowed with the norm defined by $\| v \|^2 := \sum v_i^2 \Delta x$

If I know that $\| (I -  D)^{-1} \| \leq 1$, how does $\alpha$ affect my results?

Thanks for any hint/help/reference!

Comment: If $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$ is an eigenvalue of $D$ your norm will explode.

Comment: D is exactly diagonalizable with PBC. By uniform grid, do you mean the square lattice? In this case, the eigenvalues $ D $ are something like $  4 - 2 \cos( k/N) - 2 \cos(m/N) $.